# my icons are not redirecting to the right page

Tags: html, css

for some reason when I click on the icon it doesn't redirect to the right page

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m7z40ewt/

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" 
  integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
  <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/"><i class="fab fa-researchgate" style="font-size:28px; color:#04d7aa; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding-left: 207px; padding-bottom: 11px;"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" style="font-size:30px; color:red; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding-left: 240px; padding-bottom: 10px;"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" style="font-size:25px; color:#2c61a0; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding-left: 280px; padding-bottom: 13px;"></i></a>
```

Comment: Your demo has them all pointing to `https://www.google.pt`

Comment: thats the problem i don't understand why that happens @KScandrett

Comment: nvm I updated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `position:absolute` in your icons. That means they are moved outside the corresponding link.

You need to position the anchor tags instead:

```
<a href="https://www.researchgate.net/" style="font-size:28px; color:#04d7aa; position: absolute; bottom: 11px; left: 207px;"><i class="fab fa-researchgate"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" style="font-size:30px; color:red; position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 240px;"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" style="font-size:25px; color:#2c61a0; position: absolute; bottom: 13px; left: 280px;"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
```

You're positioning them all on top of each other with `bottom: 0; left: 0`.

The last anchor will be on top. That means it will only go to [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) when trying to click the others (the Facebook link has 280px of padding to its left, which is still part of its clickable area, obscuring the icons behind it).

You should use the absolute positioning, rather than setting those values to 0.